# Let S be a bounded non-empty subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and $\bar{m} = sup S$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $S$ be a bounded non-empty subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and $\bar{m} = sup S$. Prove there is a sequence ${a_n}$ such that $a_n \in S$ for all n, and $a_n$ goes to $\bar{m}$

I want to show how to construct the sequence $a_n$ by using the properties of $sup$ characterize $\bar{m}$ as the least upper bound of $S$. Can anyone show me a formal proof of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proof:
The idea is to construct an sequence nondecreasing sequence that converges to $m$.

If $m\in S$ it is trivial (consider the constant sequence $a_n=m$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$)

If $m\notin S$ proceed as follows. Choose $a_1\in S$ such that $m-1<a_1\leq m$. Such an $a_1$ exists since $m=\sup S$. Note that $a_1 \in S$ and $m\notin S$ implies $a_1\neq m$. Thus weak inequality $a_1\leq m$ becomes strict, i.e. $a_1 < m$ and thus $0<m-a_1=|m-a_1|$. Furthermore, The inequality $m-1<a_1$ implies $m-a_1<1$ which we can rewrite as $|m-a_1|<1$. Now let $\epsilon_2=\min \{m-a_1,1/2\}$. Then $m-\epsilon_2$ is not an upperbound so that there exists $a_2 \in S$ such that $m-\epsilon_2<a_2 \leq m$. Hence we have $a_2 \neq m$ since $m\notin S$ and just as before we obtain $|m-a_2|<1/2$ and furthermore $m-\epsilon_2<a_2$ implies $m-a_2 < \epsilon_2 \leq m-a_1$ which upon deleting the middle inequality and subtracting $m$ and multiplying by $-1$ yields $a_1 \leq a_2$. This defines a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $0<|m-a_n|<1/n$ and $a_n\leq a_{n+1}$ and $a_n\leq m$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. I leave it to you to flesh out the inductive step of defining the sequence and to prove $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n =m=\sup S$.

Comment: Can you show more? I'm a bit slow on this

Comment: Sure ill edit my answer to include more details. But i should check first: are you familiar with the characterization of the supremum of a set i referred to in my answer?

Comment: Yes, I can understand the characterization

Comment: okay I updated it, sorry for the wait!

Comment: Thank you! This is very clear

Answer (score 0):

For each $n > 1$ there is a $a_n \in S$ such that : $a_n > m - \dfrac{1}{n}$.Can you take it from here?